# Ubuntu 18.04 - Activation of network connection failed

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, ethernet

I built a new computer during the past few days. There is nothing installed on it, I decided I would install Linux on it. I first tried Ubuntu 18.04 and this error showed up. My computer is connected via an ethernet cable and it detects the connection but after a short while it prints `Activation of network connection failed`.

I looked for help online and found a lot of posts but none worked. I thought maybe WiFi connection could work, so I bought a WiFi usb stick. After a lot of struggle, I managed to make it so it was detected by my computer. I could then try to connect to different WiFi access (one provided by the building I live in, the other provided by my phone in tether mode). But still, the same error was showing up.

I thought the problem was Ubuntu, I tried Mint but still not working, same issues. I have no idea what to do. The problem probably comes from my computer, but I have no idea how to fix it.

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
Mar  5 06:58:27 leop-MS-7B86 dbus-daemon[1037]: [session uid=121 pid=1037] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.13' (uid=121 pid=1047 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Mar  5 06:58:27 leop-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1583387907.7402] dhcp4 (enp34s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Mar  5 06:58:27 leop-MS-7B86 NetworkManager[839]: <info>  [1583387907.7412] dhcp4 (enp34s0): dhclient started with pid 1927
Mar  5 06:58:27 leop-MS-7B86 avahi-daemon[831]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp34s0.IPv6 with address fe80::4ec1:cc61:751:d1b8.
Mar  5 06:58:27 leop-MS-7B86 avahi-daemon[831]: New relevant interface enp34s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Mar  5 06:58:27 leop-MS-7B86 avahi-daemon[831]: Registering new address record for fe80::4ec1:cc61:751:d1b8 on enp34s0.*.
Mar  5 06:58:27 leop-MS-7B86 dbus-daemon[1037]: [session uid=121 pid=1037] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
Mar  5 06:58:27 leop-MS-7B86 dhclient[1927]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp34s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xee55893d)
Mar  5 06:58:30 leop-MS-7B86 dhclient[1927]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp34s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4 (xid=0xee55893d)
Mar  5 06:58:34 leop-MS-7B86 dhclient[1927]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp34s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0xee55893d)
Mar  5 06:58:40 leop-MS-7B86 systemd-udevd[450]: seq 3306 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:26:00.3/i2c-0/0-0008' is taking a long time
Mar  5 06:58:40 leop-MS-7B86 dhclient[1927]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp34s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xee55893d)
```

```
ifconfig
enp34s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::4ec1:cc61:751:d1b8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:d8:61:a7:3b:6b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 57  bytes 8871 (8.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 54  base 0x5000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 449  bytes 32909 (32.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 449  bytes 32909 (32.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

If you have questions about anything that could help, other commands I should type, let me know, I'll edit my post, I just don't know what is relevant. So far, given the outputs I have shown above, I'd say my DHCP protocol is failing for some reason.

Also note that my laptop can connect to my phone and to the connection provided by my building. It doesn't have an Ethernet port, so I can't test that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

WiFi now works, I am a newbie with anything related to hardware, but changing the port I was plugging the WiFi device in seemed to be *a* solution.

If anyone struggles with the same kind of problem, maybe try to plug the WiFi device in the back of your computer, directly in your motherboard (SS USB port in my case).

Note that Ethernet still doesn't work but I suspect this is related to the building providing the internet connection (or to the cable I am using, who knows).